# How to access written files without having root permissions?

Tags: android, root, android-external-storage

I have this code for write and read to file *ZIZI.txt*:

```
//=============== Write To File ZIZI.txt ===============================================
    private void writeFileToInternalStorage() {
        String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        BufferedWriter writer = null;
        try {
          writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(
              "ZIZI.txt", MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE)));
          writer.write("This is a test1." + eol);
          writer.write("This is a test2." + eol);
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
          if (writer != null) {
            try {
                writer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"OK Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    //================ Read From File ZIZI.txt ===========================================
    private void readFileFromInternalStorage() {
        String FF="";
        String eol = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        BufferedReader input = null;
        try {
          input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(openFileInput("ZIZI.txt")));
          String line;
          StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
          while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
              FF+=line+eol;
            buffer.append(line + eol);
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        if (input != null) {
          try {
            input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        }
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),FF, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I see with DDMS that the File is in: `\data\data\setup.myProject\files\ZIZI.txt`

But I can't see this file in my phone (because I don't have root permissions)

**I want to write and read from my SD card or from any folder that I can see in my
phone. How to change the code for this?**

Comment: maybe you want an app that lets you see all folders (file system) including root?

Comment: i only need to know what to change in my code that i can write & read to folder that i can see on the phone

Answer (score 0):

Have you never used the [Android Developers website?](http://developer.android.com/index.html)

Try Dev Guide -> Data Storage -> [Using the External Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

Comment: I hate this site (Android Developers website)  I always go there lost. i only need to know what to change in my code that i can write & read to folder that i can see on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the entire path to your file, using either getFilesDir for internal storage or getExternalFilesDir() for external storage. For example:

```
openFileInput(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/" + "ZIZI.txt");
```